# Spring Cloud Stream Processor Single Input, Multiple Row Output

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I've been trying to stream my json event from kafka, flatten it then push it back to another topic using Spring Cloud Stream.

input:

```
{
    "major": "Computer Science",
    "books": [{
        "title": "Learn C",
        "author": "Prof C"
    },
    {
        "title": "Learn Java",
        "author": "Java Expert"
    },{
        "title": "Learn Python",
        "author": "Python Master"
    },]
}
```

Flatten process:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT, outputChannel = Source.OUTPUT)
public String(String event){
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject rawEvent = new JSONObject(event);

    String major = rawEvent.get("major");
    JSONArray books = rawEvent.get("books");

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
        JSONObject book = books.get(i);
        book.put("major", major);
        result.put(book)
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

which only produce:

```
    [{"major":"Computer Science", "books.title":"Learn C", "books.author":"Prof C"}, 
{"major":"Computer Science", "books.title":"Learn Java", "books.author":"Java Expert"}, 
{"major":"Computer Science", "books.title":"Learn Python", "books.author":"Python Master"}]
```

My question is how to make it become like this

```
{"major":"Computer Science", "books.title":"Learn C", "books.author":"Prof C"}
{"major":"Computer Science", "books.title":"Learn Java", "books.author":"Java Expert"}
{"major":"Computer Science", "books.title":"Learn Python", "books.author":"Python Master"}
```

so I can push back in **mutilple** JSONObject not single JSONArray like what I did?

Afaik, Spring Cloud Stream output is only a single event which doesnt fit my case above to produce 3 events to Kafka.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: @Dwhitz Thanks for your input. Will update my questions then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed I misunderstood.
So in this case I'd suggest to bring in [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/). You basically have a clear case for Splitter. There are many examples out there but here is a quick snippet:

    `@Splitter
    public List<String> split(String input) {
        // basically split your input into a collection and splitter will send out each element as a separate message
    }`

Hope that helps

Comment: This is the answer that I have been looking for. Tried it and works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you've produced is a valid JSON array. What you trying to produce is not a valid JSON. But as long as you're ok with that you can simply use StringBuilder and append each *book.toString()* to it (instead of JSONArray). That will at least produce what you are looking for.

Also, this is really not a question related to Spring Cloud Stream, rather general Java/JSON question, so I suppose there are more specific forums on StackOverflow that can get you a better answer.

Comment: sorry, seems like you misunderstood my question. What I want is to push 3 events instead of 1 event to the Kafka. afaik, Spring Cloud Stream will only produce 1 output.
Thanks for the input though

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood.